# How to disable UC browser news feeds?

Tags: feed, mobile-browser, uc-browser

On the latest update of  UCBrowser ( V11.0.0.828 ) android lots of annoying news feeds are there. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems in the latest update (V11.0.8.885) UC browser is allowing users to disable UC NEWS.

> Settings -> Homepage Settings -> UC News Display (On/ Off)

:)

- in home page scroll down to the end. click manage cards unchecked all.

Comment: Why downvote? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Open  your UC Browser then  just scroll down after doing that there is a plus sign button at top right side click on that and tap on edit and then select which type of news you want whatever you dont want then tap on × button then click on done.But there is no option to remove recommend from uc news feeds.

Answer (score -1):

Go to home page setting and uc news display change to card now restart automatically  now go uc news manage cards turn of all news that time do not use mobile data.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes uc news install s  automatically    then disconnect data and disable all unknown application... Even fake WhatsApp a application will also be installed which re installs uc news ..then restart phone check for running application if any thing runs disable it.. clear all cache data of disable apps.